# Is it possible to query data of network usage before the installation date of the app

Tags: android, kotlin, networkstatsmanager

I'm writing a part of an app that displays mobile data usage and I also want it to display data from before the user installed the app. Currently, whenever I query data for a time range before the app was installed on a certain device, `NetworkStatsManager.queryDetails` returns a `NetworkStats` object containing no buckets.

I've already managed to get correct data about mobile data usage after the installation date in the app.

The weird thing is that I've tried to delete all cache/data in the settings and uninstall and reinstall the app. After this, the app is still able to query data from before uninstalling it, but not from before the very first time I installed the app. My gut feeling is that Android does not let you acces data from before the `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`, the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` or the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions are granted by the user.

The documentation of [NetworkStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStats) and [NetworkStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html) don't seem to mention anything about data history.

The NetworkStatsManager is obtained like this:

```
val networkStatsManager by lazy {
                context.getSystemService(Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE) as NetworkStatsManager
}
```

and the NetworkStats object is obtained here:

```
                mobileDataNetworkStats = networkStatsManager.queryDetails(
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
                        getSubscriberId(context, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE),
                        from.time,
                        to.time)
```

And this is how I iterate over the buckets

```
            val bucket: NetworkStats.Bucket = NetworkStats.Bucket()
            mobileDataNetworkStats.getNextBucket(bucket)

            var currentUsage = usagePerUid[bucket.uid]
            currentUsage = when (currentUsage) {
                null -> 0
                else -> currentUsage
            }

            currentUsage += bucket.rxBytes
            currentUsage += bucket.txBytes

            usagePerUid[bucket.uid] = currentUsage
```

So is it possible to obtain buckets via `queryDetails` or `querySummary` from before the installation date (or from before the date that permisisons were granted by the user)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Just pick to InternalStatManager the time that you want

```
val summaryStats = networkStatManager!!.querySummary(
            networkType, subscriberId, startTime, endTime
        )
```